# How to make a view resize on swipe within a photo collage for iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, photo, image-resizing

I'm writing a photo editor demo that user can swipe horizontally or vertically to split the views to many small views they want, then users can drag the borders of each views to re-size the view. The problems is I don't know how to make a photo collage that user can drag the view border to make the size of views change. I think every white border (from the picture below) is a view, so user can drag it but I don't know what should to do then. Can you give me some suggestion?

[image]

Comment: You could do this a few different ways. You could have it just be an image, and get the size/boundingBox of the image and display a white border around it, Then when the user `saves` convert all the images into one `UIImageView`

Comment: Thanks CodeBandits, but I think there're some misunderstanding. I just want to know how to drag the white border then the size of image frame change.

Comment: @QuangLuu Hey you got the solution of the collage ?. Please let me know. I'm on the critical condition so please dear help me. I'm really very thankful to u.

Comment: @QuangLuu if u done  with ur problem could u tell me how i could achieve it

Comment: @Imran: Brieftly, the white rectangle is actually a view. I scaled the imageviews affected's size based on the white rectangle position.

Comment: @QuangLuu could u upload code in github and share it. It would be a great help

Comment: @QuangLuu Can you please Upload this project on github