# UIView in the shape of a light bulb

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, cashapelayer

how can I create a view in the shape of a light bulb with `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triangular UIView or UIImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21776253/triangular-uiview-or-uiimageview), exact same principle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a Tool called [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/),you can put image or draw path on it.It will return a path.

Then you create a `CAShaperLayer` with this path. Then set mask layer

```
yourview.layer.mask = yourLayer;
yourview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't accomplish this using an `UIView`'s `frame` property. You could do this using a `CALayer` like [`CAShapeLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class). You have to set it's `path` property accordingly.