# How to Implement photo editor Collage in swift 3

Tags: ios, layout, swift3

I want to create Photo Collage with customised layout as following image. i am not getting idea about how can i create collage in swift3. .I am confused about using UIView controller or UICollectionView.Please anyone suggest me that how can i implement it

**Please Note:** I have tried Collection view and also referred This tutorial : [How to make collage of images according to different shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619968/how-to-make-collage-of-images-according-to-different-shapes/)  but its not working properly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create UICollectionView with custom layout to create photo editor collage.Please follow this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make static Photo College you may take single view and design it with UIImageView as per your need. And display album photo from gallery.

If you want to make dynamic Photo College you have to use UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate.
For that you can refer

https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2

https://shrikar.com/ios-swift-tutorial-uicollectionview-pinterest-layout/

Thank You!!!